# How to draw fields of different types using for:each in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, fields, loop, inputfield, template

I'm trying to draw a set of different fields (with type text, number, picklist and other) using for:each, but I get all identical fields (they differ only in names and labels). How can this be fixed? Who knows a better way?

[image]
[image]

```
<template for:each={fields} for:item="f" for:index="index">
     <div key={f.Id}>
          <div class="slds-size_1-of-4 slds-var-p-around_xxx-small"> 
               <lightning-input 
                    class="candidate"
                    data-index={index}
                    name={f.name} 
                    label={f.label} 
                    type={f.type} 
                    required={f.required}
                    value=""
               ></lightning-input>
          </div>
     </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type property, like pretty much everything in LWC, is `cAsE-sEnSiTiVe`. Use all lowercase letters (`text`, `email`, etc). Note that if you want to use picklists, you'll also need to alternatively render lightning-select as well.

```
<lightning-select if:true={f.isPicklist} ...
<lightning-input if:false={f.isPicklist} ...
```

Which means you'll also need to calculate that value:

```
this.fields = this.fields.map(field => ({...field, isPicklist: field.type === 'picklist' }));
```

Comment: Thank you) But I've already deal with it. Just using lightning-record-edit-form and lightning-input-field, that needs only api-names of fields